# SonarQube delegate authentication to GitLab fail [404 not found]

Tags: oauth-2.0, gitlab, sonarqube, http-status-code-404

## Context:

- Sonarqube: 9.2.4.50792 --> https://sonar.dev.mycompany.com/
- Gitlab: 13.4.3-ee --> http://git.mycomany.com/

## What I am trying to achieve:

I try to delegate SonarQube authentication to Gitlab Self-Hosted.

## What I've done:

Following [the official SonarQube documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/gitlab-integration/), I've created a "[GitLab OAuth app](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/gitlab-integration/)":

1. Went to http://git.mycompany.com/admin/applications
2. New Application:

   - Name: SonarQube
   - Redirect URI: https://sonar.dev.mycompany.com/oauth2/callback/gitlab
   - Trusted: Checked
   - Confidential: Checked
   - Scopes: all checked, to be sure my issue was not an access issue. (I'll tune it later)
3. I have copied both Application ID and Secret to use later.
4. Went to https://sonar.dev.mycompany.com/admin/settings?alm=gitlab&category=almintegration
5. GitLab Authentication:

   - Enabled: Yes, of course
   - GitLab URL: http://git.mycompany.com/users/auth/gitlab/callback
   - Application ID: The one given by GitLab during step 2
   - Secret: The one given by GitLab during step 2
   - Allow users to sign-up: Enabled
   - Synchronize user groups: Enabled
6. Disconnected to my admin account
7. The new Log in with GitLab is well shown:

[image: Log in with GitLab logo]

8. When I clicked on this new button, I was well redirected to my GitLab instance (URL: http://git.mycompany.com/users/sign_in).

[image: GitLab Sign in]

9. I was using my GitLab credentials then clicked on "Sign in"
10. I've got a GitLab 404 error page:

[image: GitLab Error 404]

The URL was:

```
http://git.mycompany.com/users/auth/gitlab/callback/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<MY_APPLICATION_ID>&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsonar.dev.mycompany.com%3A9000%2Foauth2%2Fcallback%2Fgitlab&scope=api&state=ai1rq82joi504ggv3nc1qa0h29
```

The redirect_uri seems to be constructed with my sonar.properties informations (html_encoded):

```
"http://" + sonar.web.host + ":" sonar.web.port + "oauth2/callback/gitlab"
```

## Investigation:

While I'm reproducing this error, I'm following (tail -f) some log files:

```
root@sonar.dev.mycompany.com: tail -f /var/log/httpd/*_log /var/log/message /home/sonar/sonarqube/logs/*.log
```

As expected, there is no information regarding the error 404 on GitLab.
On my GitLab server :

```
root@git.mycompany.com: tail -f /var/log/httpd/*_log /var/log/message /var/log/gitlab/*/current
```

And a message appears:

```
==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/current <==
{
   "correlation_id":"ZUVztnRFFe9",
   "duration_ms":62,
   "host":"git.mycompany.com",
   "level":"info",
   "method":"GET",
   "msg":"access",
   "proto":"HTTP/1.1",
   "referrer":"",
   "remote_addr":"127.0.0.1:0",
   "remote_ip":"127.0.0.1",
   "status":404,
   "system":"http",
   "time":"2022-01-19T18:06:47+01:00",
   "uri":"/users/auth/gitlab/callback/oauth/authorize?response_type=code\u0026client_id=<MY_APPLICATION_ID>\u0026redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsonar.dev.mycompany.com%3A9000%2Foauth2%2Fcallback%2Fgitlab\u0026scope=api\u0026state=16r2cvc196v4fj8k0rv7oprs6h",
   "user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36 Edg/97.0.1072.62",
   "written_bytes":28281
}
```

Is there anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your Redirect URL is http and your sonarqube https... I hope you get the problem